# Google Play Services Library not working

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, location-services

My current workspoace setup is as follows:
Android SDK Tools: Rev 24.4.1
Android SDK Platform-tools Rev 23.1
Android SDK Build-tools Rev 23.0.2
Google Play Services Rev 29

All of the above are latest Rev as of today.
In my project I am using Google API of Android 4.4.2

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="23"/>
```

I imported the Google Play Serviecs Library project into my workspace.
It was giving following error messages:

```
\google-play-services_lib\res\values-v11\appinvite_styles.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'.
\google-play-services_lib\res\values-v21\appinvite_styles.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'.
```

As per a online answer, I changed its project build target to latest 6.0 Marshmallow Google API and these errors got resolved for me.

Then I added it as a library project, under my project Properties -> Android, but now my project started giving same error messages:

```
\google-play-services_lib\res\values-v21\appinvite_styles.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'.
\google-play-services_lib\res\values-v21\appinvite_styles.xml:5: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DialogWhenLarge.NoActionBar'.
```

So I changed my projects its project build target to latest 6.0 Marshmallow Google API and these errors got resolved but while running this application I got a new error message:

```
Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
```

I google it and found this happens when number of refernces in project are exceeding 65536
Since my project includes only 1 Activity, which is for Location API, hence I assume it has something to do with references within Google Play Services API under Marshmallow 6.0

Hence I rolled back the Project build target to 4.4.2 Google API.
As expected it resume giving old errors in my project.
Hence I removed the Google Play Services API project from Android -> Library and added it as a project in Java Build Path.
As I am still using Eclipse, I whnt ahead and moved Gooigle Play Services project to the top in Order & Export of Java Build Path.

Now I clean & build my project.
Upon running my project I get another error message:
In console: `google-play-services_lib] Could not find google-play-services_lib.apk!`
In Logcat: `Failed resolving Lcom/example/testandroid/MainActivity; interface 1461 'Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks;'`

My code imports look like this:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStatusCodes;
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
LocationListener {

}
```

I have went through all the forums online and nothing has helped so far.
Please help.

Thanks!

EDIT: My project dependencies are as in screenshot below:
[image: ProjectDependencies]

Comment: It might be your min sdk level.  Holo doesn't exist until v3.0 or 3.0, which are 11 and 15 respectively.  Do you have the compatibility library as part of your project?  If not, add it.

Comment: why will google release it's google play services library with minsdkversion = 9 when Holo is not supported in it. Anyways after your suggestion I tried changing the minSdkVersion of GooglePlayServicesLib to 19. And the problem still exists

Comment: Not sure.  THe "Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536" I do know though-  do you have a very large app or using lots of libraries?  There's a maximum of 65,535 methods in a single dex file.  If you need more than that, you need to make your apk multi-dex.  http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: @GabeSechan As I mentioned in my question, I am having only 1 activity in code. This activity don't have many reference. All it is doing is, calling Location service of Google play. So I assume whenever we include Google Play Services API in 6.0 Project Build target, it crosses 65k mark.

Comment: can you provide us with the .gradle to see the dependencies you've set? For now, you can look at how to properly [setup the Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) to see if anything was missed or done incorrectly.

Comment: @adjuremods I have added a screenshot in my question above. Due to team setup, I am still stuck with eclipse ADT. I guess these are the dependencies you were willing to see? As you can figure out from the steps I followed, mentioned in my question, I have followed everything from the link shared by you.

Comment: It looks like your project setup is not properly configured. From what I experienced, `google-play-services_lib` should be imported as a project, configured as a library, and added as a library in the `Android` tab of the project section. You can look at this [tutorial](http://hmkcode.com/adding-google-play-services-library-to-your-android-app/) on how to add the library in the android app. I'll still encourage you to migrate to Android Studio since Google already dropped its support in ADT.

Comment: @adjuremods I know it's high time to move on to Android Studio but unfortunately, due to project restrictions, I can't do that before May. I mentioned in my question above As per google documentation I imported the google-play-services-lib as a library under Android tab as well. It started giving me error in my project. This error is actually coming from google-play-services-lib